# Linking 2 UI (User Interface) Objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, user-controls

I want to make 2 sliders in matlab so that whenever the position of either changes, the 'Callback function' will automatically have access to both UI objects' values. Essentially, the goal of this is to use the sliders to navigate a 2-dimensional variable space....

The issue is, it seems that each sliders' callback function only has access to its value... I am trying to get it to access both.

Here is the relevant part of my code so far:

```
slider1= uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',1,'Max',N,'Position',[200 130 200 20]);
slider2= uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',1,'Max',N,'Position',[200 100 200 20]);
        set(slider1,'Callback',{@makeWin3, %relevant variables% );
        set(slider2,'Callback',{@makeWin3, %relevant variables% );
```

The callback function looks like this:

```
 function [] = makeWin3(hObj,notused, %relevant variables%)
    n=round(hObj.Value);     %value of calling slider
 end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a safe bet would be to store both sliders in the handles structure of your GUI, then you could easily access them from any function you call or from within the GUI of course.

For example, while defining the ui components, assuming the figure is also stored in the handles structure when creating it:

```
%// Create figure
handles.fig = figure(define figure properties here...)

handles.slider1= uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',1,'Max',N,'Position',[200 130 200 20]);
handles.slider2= uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',1,'Max',N,'Position',[200 100 200 20]);
        set(handles.slider1,'Callback',{@makeWin3, %relevant variables% );
        set(handles.slider2,'Callback',{@makeWin3, %relevant variables% );  

%// Store/update the handles in the handles structure with guidata.
guidata(handles.fig,handles); %// Save handles structure of GUI.
```

Then in your callback function, you can retrieve the handles structure like so:

```
function [] = makeWin3(hObj,notused, %relevant variables%)

%// Retrieve elements from handles structure.

   handles = guidata(handles.fig);
   n=round(get(handles.sliderX,'Value'));     %value of calling slider
 end
```

An alternative solution would be to pass the handles structure as an argument to your callback function.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome then glad to help!